# Use multiple templates with KnpPaginatorBundle

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-2.5, knppaginator

I use KnpPaginatorBundle to manage pagination in the backoffice of my site and it works well

I configured it to use a custom templates

```
knp_paginator:
    template:
        pagination: MyappMainBundle::pagination.html.twig
```

Then, I want to use the same bundle in the frontoffice but with different html structure.
So, my question is : Is it possible to have two templates for the pagination? One for the backoffice and One for the frontoffice.

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can customise the pagination template in the controller:

```
$paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');
$pagination = $paginator->paginate($target, $page);
$pagination->setTemplate('MyBundle:Pagination:pagination.html.twig');
$pagination->setSortableTemplate('MyBundle:Pagination:sortable.html.twig');
```

In the View:

```
{% do pagination.setTemplate('MyBundle:Pagination:pagination.html.twig') %}
```

or (better) in the render method:

```
{{ knp_pagination_render(pagination, 'MyBundle:Pagination:pagination.html.twig') }}
```

More info in [the doc of the bundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/templates.md)

Comment: Thanks :) ! I didn't see this part of doc

Comment: Hi @MarioJohnathan you are welcome! Which method you applied?

Comment: I used the **{% do pagination %}** in the twig template because I used to do the same with forms via the method [{% form_theme %}](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#method-1-inside-the-same-template-as-the-form) .
That way, I can also reuse "knp_pagination_render" several times in the same file without calling the template multiple times

Comment: Alternatively you could extend the `Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\Twig\Extension\PaginationExtension` with your own twig functions like `acme_pagination_render_backoffice()` that then calls the `return $this->render($paginator, '::backoffice_paginator.html.twig', $queryParam, $viewParams)` method with the templates already set. That way you wouldn't need to set the template on each usage of the renderer paginator.